# is there any way to select branches from multiple repositories in CI build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have trigger in azure-pipelines.yaml like below.

```
resources:
    repositories:
        - repository: APPLICATION
          type: git
          name: AAA/APPLICATION
          ref: master
        - repository: TESTS
          type: git
          name: AAA/TESTS
          ref: master
STAGES:
  - stage : BuildApplication
    // checkout branch & build necessary things
  - stage : BuildTests
    // checkout branch & build necessary things
```

Since the yaml resides in Application repository, While creating manual CI build I am able to select the Branches in Application repository & for Tests repository the branch checkout will be master always.

is there any was I can able to set the branch details of Tests repository before creating release ?

Comment: I don't understand what difficulty you're having. Please explain your scenario in more detail and provide more complete YAML and explain what behavior isn't occurring that you'd like to occur. You can check out any repository resource with the `- checkout` step, and when queuing a pipeline, you can choose which version of the resource should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any was I can able to set the branch details of Tests repository before creating release ?

From your YAML sample, you need to select the Resource Repo branch when manually running the pipeline.

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can select the resource repo branch. The branch is defined at resources field. When you running the pipeline, it will use the default branch.

For a workaround, you can change to define the repo in check out field. You can use paramter to define the repo branches and then you can select the branch when you running the pipeline.

Refer to this doc: [Inline syntax checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#inline-syntax-checkout)

Here is an example:

```
parameters:
  - name: test
    values:
      - refs/heads/main
      - refs/heads/test1



pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout:  git://azure/Repo13@${{ parameters.test }}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for notifying about parameters. I have used type as String so I can set some value to this field during the build creation and checkout the branch manually using this value.